# Get the column name as a parameter from SP and set a value to that Column with in the procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

```
ALTER proc [dbo].[sp_dosomethingwithStudentAttn] @AttnList as dbo.StudentAttendanceList readonly,@DeptId int,@SemId int,@SecId int,@DayId int,@currentDate date,@period nvarchar(5)
as
declare @IfStudentDayWiseAttnExists as bit,
        @updateQuery as varchar(max),
        @insertQuery as varchar(max)

begin

set nocount on
declare 
    @stnId as int,
    @stnAttnStatus as nvarchar
declare cur_UpdateInsertStnAttnData cursor  forward_only static for  
    select StudentId,AttdnStatus  from @AttnList
open cur_UpdateInsertStnAttnData
if @@CURSOR_ROWS>0
begin
    fetch next from cur_UpdateInsertStnAttnData into @stnId,@stnAttnStatus
    while @@FETCH_STATUS=0
    begin

        set @IfStudentDayWiseAttnExists=(select case when exists 
                                            (
                                                select * from tbl_DailyAttend 
                                                where DeptId=@DeptId and 
                                                SemId=@SemId and 
                                                SecId=@SecId and 
                                                attDate=@currentDate and 
                                                StuId=@stnId
                                            )
                                            then CAST(1 AS bit)
                                            else CAST(0 as bit)
                                            end
                                         )

         if @IfStudentDayWiseAttnExists='true'
         begin
            if @stnAttnStatus='true'
            begin
                select @updateQuery='update tbl_DailyAttend set '+@period+'=''true'' where DeptId='+@DeptId+' and SemId='+@SemId+' and SecId='+@SecId+' and attDate='+CONVERT(date, @currentDate)+' and StuId='+@stnId+''
                EXEC  (@updateQuery)
            end
            else
            begin
                select @updateQuery='update tbl_DailyAttend set '+@period+'=''false'' where DeptId='+@DeptId+' and SemId='+@SemId+' and SecId='+@SecId+' and attDate='+CONVERT(date, @currentDate)+' and StuId='+@stnId+''
                EXEC  (@updateQuery)
            end

         end
         else
         begin                               
            set @insertQuery='insert into tbl_DailyAttend (DeptId,SemId,SecId,DayId,attDate,'+@period+') values ('+@DeptId+','+@SemId+','+@SecId+','+@DayId+','+@currentDate+','+@stnAttnStatus+')'
         end

        fetch next from cur_UpdateInsertStnAttnData into @stnId,@stnAttnStatus
    end
end
end
```

[image: OP's picture of the Error]

Comment: you should add your error message text in the question itself rather than attaching an image.

Comment: I think you can use `MERGE` for a simpler stored procedure ;).

Comment: Side note: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are building dynamic Sql, you need to build up the statements as strings - i.e. you can't concatenate a date into the query (`... ='+CONVERT(date, @currentDate)+' ...`).

You should also try and parameterize the dynamic query as far as possible as this will reduce the Sql Injection surface attack area. For example, in the update query, everything can be parameterized with the exception of the dynamic column name (`@period`). Use `sp_executesql` to pass parameters, and the corresponding types across the dynamic query:

```
DECLARE @updateQuery as NVARCHAR(max);

SELECT @updateQuery=
     N'update tbl_DailyAttend set ' + @period + N'=''true'' 
       where DeptId=@DeptId and SemId=@SemId and SecId=@SecId 
             and attDate = @currentDate and StuId=@stnId';

sp_executesql @updateQuery, 
     N'@DeptId int, 
       @SemId int, 
       @SecId int, 
       @DayId int, 
       @currentDate date,
       @stnId as int',
      @DeptId = @DeptId, 
      @SemId = @SemId, 
      @SecId = @SecId, 
      @DayId = @DayId, 
      @currentDate = @currentDate,
      @stnId = @stnId';
```

To reduce injection attack on the dynamic column name, you can also check that the column exists in the table prior to executing the query (e.g. from `sys.columns`)